# How to generate jOOQ classes from Testcontainers database migrated with Flyway during Gradle build?

Tags: gradle, jooq, flyway, testcontainers, jooq-codegen

I am trying to generate `jOOQ` classes from a database running in docker container(`Testcontainers`) which will be migrated with `flyway` during `gradle` build. I am new to gradle and I created working proof of concept which does not feel right, because I have to start the container in configuration phase, so the database `url`, `password` and `username` are available to configuration extensions(`flyway` and `jooq`). Then I have to register container stop using deprecated method `buildFinished`

I would like for the container to start only when `generateJooq` task needs to be run. Ideally there would be three tasks, first would start the container with database, second would migrate the started database with flyway and third would generate jooq classes, and after that, stop the running container. Any advice how to do that?

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer

plugins {
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "8.5.13"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "7.1.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.17.3")
        classpath("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.14")
    }
}

val flywayMigration: Configuration by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    flywayMigration("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3")
    jooqGenerator("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0")
}
var instance: PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>? = null

task("postgreSQLContainer") {
    instance = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:11.6")
    instance?.start()

    gradle.buildFinished {
        if (instance?.isRunning == true) {
            instance?.stop()
        }
    }
}


flyway {
    configurations = arrayOf("flywayMigration")
    url = instance?.jdbcUrl
    user = instance?.username
    password = instance?.password
}

jooq {
    configurations {
        create("main") {
            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
                jdbc.apply {
                    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
                    url = flyway.url
                    user = flyway.user
                    password = flyway.password
                }

                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        inputSchema = "public"
                    }
                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "com.cleevio.jooq"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named<nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqGenerate>("generateJooq") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("postgreSQLContainer"))
    dependsOn(tasks.named("flywayMigrate"))

    inputs.files(fileTree("src/main/resources/db/migration"))
        .withPropertyName("migrations")
        .withPathSensitivity(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)

    allInputsDeclared.set(true)
}
```

Comment: Did you check this blog post by jOOQ?

Comment: Did you link something?

Comment: Oh sorry, here we go: https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/
This is for Maven, but you should be able to conceptually replicate it for Gradle.